# my data won't update php - sql

Tags: php, sql, database, select, sql-update

Hello I try to update a data in my sql with php.

First I connect to my database

```
try
{
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cruel', 'root', '');
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
die('Erreur : ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

After I take my var from my other page I check if empty

```
 if (isSet($_POST['radio']) ) 
    {

        $timVerified = ($_POST['radio']) ;
        echo($_POST['radio']);
    }else{
        echo('Aucun changement à été effectué. ');

    }
```

I make a request to select all my data I need

```
$requete = $bdd->prepare('SELECT timVerified,usrId, timChoice,prtTimeSheetId,timId,timUserId  FROM projetstaches ,users,timesheets   ');
$requete->execute() or die(print_r($requete->errorInfo()));
$resultat = $requete->fetch();
```

And here is the problem It's won't update here

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE timesheets (timVerified) SET timVerified = :timVerified SELECT MAX(prtTimeSheetId) FROM projetstaches WHERE usrId = 7 AND timId = prtTimeSheetId AND timUserId = usrID' ); 
 $req->execute(array(
      ':timVerified' => $timVerified
     ));
```

Could someone help me? ( i use wampserver, notepadd ++ for software)

**EDIT** For fred the error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(prtTimeSheetId) FROM projetstaches WHERE usrId = 7 AND timId = prtTim' at line 1' in C:\wamp\www\testlp\completecheck.php on line 38

and

> ( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT MAX(prtTimeSheetId) FROM projetstaches WHERE usrId = 7 AND timId = prtTim' at line 1 in C:\wamp\www\testlp\completecheck.php on line 38

For Michael **EDIT**

http://pastebin.com/6LBwGtc3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since none of the columns from `projetstaches` are referenced in the `UPDATE`, and the most recent record per `timUserId` can be determined by ordering `timesheet`, the `JOIN` is unnecessary, and indeed all the other tables are unnecessary.  Using `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`, you can target the specific record.

Sort by `timCreateDate DESC` and by `timId` for the cases where two share the same date since it is a `DATE` column rather than a `DATETIME`.

```
UPDATE timesheets 
SET timVerified = :timVerified
WHERE timUserId = 7
ORDER BY
  timCreatedDate DESC,
  timId DESC
# Crucially, LIMIT 1 to target one record only (the first in the sort)
LIMIT 1
```

Reference [MySQL `UPDATE` syntax reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

The query as printed above can be placed directly into your `PDO` code with the `execute()` call and its array parameter defined as you already have it.

Note: I would recommend changing the `timCreatedDate` from a `DATE` type to `DATETIME` so that you may target it with more granularity. If you did that, you may not need to use `timId DESC` in the `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line updating your MySQL from

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE timesheets (timVerified) SET timVerified = :timVerified SELECT MAX(prtTimeSheetId) FROM projetstaches WHERE usrId = 7 AND timId = prtTimeSheetId AND timUserId = usrID' );
```

to

```
$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE timesheets SET timVerified = :timVerified SELECT MAX(prtTimeSheetId) FROM projetstaches WHERE usrId = 7 AND timId = prtTimeSheetId AND timUserId = usrID' );
```

i.e. remove the (timVerified)